# Select three divs with attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide/show three divs based on attribute value.

Basically, **.foo1, .foo2 and foo3 should be hidden until attribute value is `[ccaction=new]` and when attribute value changed with JS to `[ccaction=edit]` then foo1, foo2, and foo3 should be visible.**

I tried to **hide/show** them with different ways like this

```
[ccaction=new] .foo1 .foo2 .foo3 {

display: none !important; 
}

[ccaction=edit] .foo1 .foo2 .foo3 {

display: block !important; 
}
```

But i think i am doing mistake somewhere. I am not sure where i am making mistaking.

Can someone help to find mistake?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Divs don't have a value attribute. Inputs have a value attribute.

Comment: Just one input have attribute. I am trying to select 3 divs based on input value attribute

Comment: Your selectors for `foo` do not have `.` if you are trying to select class...

Comment: sorry, i forget to add class `.`

Comment: Kindly provide your html snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help you:

```
div[ccaction="new"] {
display: none !important; 
}

div[ccaction="edit"] {
display: block !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do this:

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $div = $('#myDiv'),
    current = $div.attr('ccaction'),
    new_str = current == 'new' ? 'edit' : 'new';

  $div.attr('ccaction', new_str);
});
```

```css
div[ccaction="new"] .foo1,
div[ccaction="new"] .foo2,
div[ccaction="new"] .foo3 {
  display: none !important;
}
div[ccaction="edit"] .foo1,
div[ccaction="edit"] .foo2,
div[ccaction="edit"] .foo3 {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to toggle new/edit ccaction attr</button>
<div ccaction="new" id="myDiv">
  <div class="foo1">Foo1</div>
  <div class="foo2">Foo2</div>
  <div class="foo3">Foo3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not helpful. Try actually providing your code?

Comment: Your HTML? I see none.

Comment: Is there any way that i can select based on selection. Like, If [ccaction="new"] then display none foo 1 2 3 and if [ccaction="edit"] then foo 1 2 3 block?